# How to listen for JTable row and col change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Someone can explain me how events for row change work?
I don't want to edit my cell, only know when the current row or column are changing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> know when the current row or column are changing.

For the row:

1. Add a `ListSelectionListener` to the `ListSelectionModel` of the `JTable`.

For the column:

1. Add a `ListSelectionListener` to the `ListSelectionModel` of the `TableColumnModel` of the `JTable`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for a basic example.